# Receive JMS messages only on node they in which they were produced

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am using Spring's `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` to receive messages from an ActiveMQ queue. This application is the sole producer of messages to this queue. The application is clustered so in the case that I have two instances (`instance1`, `instance2`) how can I ensure that messages produced and sent to the queue from `instance1` are received by the message listener on `instance1` and messages produced and sent to the queue from `instance2` are received by the message listener on `instance2`? My initial though was to set the `messageSelector` property of the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, but I'd like each application to have the same configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that; you either need a separate queue for each instance or use a message selector.

Comment: Thank you. After asking this last night I thought about just adding a suffix to the queue which is specified as a placeholder and passed in as a JVM option. This is working perfect now.

Comment: Granted, queues can be fairly light-weight, but if you have any number of nodes it becomes decently unmanageable.  Gary is write, message selector is good, add your own JMS property to identify the node and then create the appropriate message selector so a node only gets its own messages.